# Jooq CastException on Spring Boot context refreshed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jooq

when spring boot first startup, jooq works well.
but if i make change to code and after spring boot context refreshed, 
then i stucked in trouble with class cast exception.
the problem is cast exception on same class.

my boot conf is :

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
public ExecuteListener exceptionTransformer() {
    return new DefaultExecuteListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void exception(ExecuteContext context) {
            SQLDialect dialect = context.configuration().dialect();
            SQLExceptionTranslator translator = (dialect != null)
                ? new SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator(dialect.name())
                : new SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator();
            context.exception(
                translator.translate("jOOQ", context.sql(), context.sqlException()));
        }
    };
}
@Primary
@Bean
public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
    return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
}
public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
    return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
}
public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
    DefaultConfiguration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration();
    configuration.set(connectionProvider());
    configuration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(exceptionTransformer()));
    configuration.set(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    // @formatter:off
    configuration.set(
        new Settings()
        .withExecuteLogging(true)
        .withRenderFormatted(true)
        );
    // @formatter:on
    configuration.set(SfmRecordMapperProviderFactory.newInstance().ignorePropertyNotFound().newProvider());
    return configuration;
}
```

query code is :

```
User user = dsl.select()
    .from(USER)
    .where(USER.USER_ID.eq(id)).fetchOneInto(User.class);
```

admin.domain.User is:

```
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String userId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String pswd;
    private String name;
    private String useYn;
    private Timestamp registDatetime;
    private Timestamp updateDatetime;
}
```

stack trace is :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: admin.domain.User cannot be cast to admin.domain.User
    at admin.dao.UserDao.getUserByIdWithRoles(UserDao.java:123)
    at admin.dao.UserDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f7b71f39.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

what is my fault?

Comment: Clearly, this seems to be a class loading problem. I would suspect that your *change the code* action involves re-generating some jOOQ-generated classes. Could you describe how that re-generation happens, and how exactly you're refreshing the spring boot context?

Comment: @Lukas Eder your code gives me much hits!

Comment: @LukasEder is right about CL. The same class is not the same class if it was loaded by a different Class Loader. The class what creates the admin.domain.User (jooq?) is using one CL while the DAO itself was loaded by a different one. One of those is lost and recreated on the reload while the other isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have spring boot automatic restart enabled?

This look likes it, you could try:

- to run without the devtools (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable)
- add the correct path to your live reload (
  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-additional-paths and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload )

:)

Comment: then you don't use spring boot automatic restart anymore, so it was most likely the culprit.

Comment: no! I just want my team walk through jooq away from mybatis.

Comment: no! I just want my team walk through jooq away from mybatis. first time I suggest JPA, but my team complain me about JPA.so next I search  about jooq. and i tested it's usability. i satisfied about jooq. but my team needs restart stadibility in development env. when i stucked in cast problem, it's over my ability to slove it in time.
I don't have much time to solve it, but I want my team move forward. so next my suggestion is jrebel. I'm not quit, just needs more time. Thank you for your attention. I'm not good at english, but you may know my intentions.